# GF 4 and JSF 2.2 logging

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish

I trying to use newest GF 4 and JSF 2.2 and I can't see any logging output from my app. Neither system.out.print nor java logger not gives any output to log.
Is there an known issue or misconfiguration problem?

Comment: Please post your properties or xml file for logging so that one can see where you are missing.

Comment: I have no specaial settings in project and I have fresh GF isnstallation. The same app gives me proper logging on gf 3.1.